# how to send a blocking message via HandlerThread?

Tags: java, android

I need to send a message to a HandlerThread from my current thread but stop the sendmessage call from returning immediately. Is there a way to do this sendMessage() in a blocking way?

Comment: blocking? why would you do that?

Comment: well i need to do a ui update from inside a seperate thread and i'd like to wait until the ui update is done before i continue in the other thread.

Comment: Please post the code what you have tried.

Comment: try this :http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

Comment: Why not simply send a message from UI thread (I assume you update UI from UI thread only) to your worker thread when you're ready? The worker thread could simply post an update req and then wait for "ready" message. Perhaps you need to clarify the goal more.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i think the solution should be.

```
// This handler will be associated with the UI thread
Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    textView.setText("Progress: " + msg.what);          
  }
};

private void CreateThread() {
  Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
      {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("Error: ", e.toString());
        }

          // You can update the UI by sending messages to the UI thread
          uiHandler.sendMessage(uiHandler.obtainMessage(i));
        }
      }
    }
  };
  t.start();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no. what should happen ideally is that uiHandler.sendMessage(uiHandler.obtainMessage(i)); shouldn't return until uiHandler completes processing the message. Visual c++ sendmessage behaves in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) class. I would create an exchanger, send a Runnable having access to that exchanger, and synchronize on that exchanger. This way the exchanger would give me the results obtained asynchronously. You may think out something that would work with messages.

Note that a thread that calls `Exchanger.exchange()` may have to wait for a long time! (You may get an ANR if you call it from the UI thread.)